# When doing qpush, can I get a merge tool instead of .rej files?

Tags: mercurial, hgsubversion, mercurial-queue

I've recently start using mq, which is a great way of working.  One thing that annoys me slightly is that when I qpush back my patches after doing a pull and update, I end up with .rej files if there are conflicts.

It would be nice if Mercurial could just open TortoiseMerge so I can resolve the conflicts as quickly as possible, instead of having to open the .rej files one by one and do it in a more manual, slower way.

Even svn-style conflicts markers inside the files would be easier to work with than the .rej files.

Is there a way around those .rej files?

Comment: It looks like rebasing the new changes on top of my patches can be a solution, but can I still refresh the patches individually then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg pull --rebase` works, as long as you want to rebase your patches onto a newer base. You need have the patches you want to rebase qpushed. If the revision you want to rebase on is already in your repo, strip it and pull from the strip-backup bundle.

Comment: I tried, but I think I messed it up somehow.  But I assume you won't be able to update more than one patch this way, so it doesn't really help for what I'm doing.

Comment: No, it does rebase the entire series.

Comment: Sure, but you can't individually edit and qrefresh the patches.  You have to qpush one at a time for that, and then you're back to to original problem.  I guess I have to wait until mq adds support for merge tools instead of creating .rej files.

Comment: No, if I understand correctly, it does exactly what you want. It merges every applied mq patch individually and refreshes it. When conflicts arise, it stops, leaves conflict markers, lets you clean up and tells you how to continue (I think hg rebase --continue). You never get .rej files this way.

Comment: Ok, so it basically qpushes one patch at a time, then stops and lets you fix it when there are conflicts?  That sounds like exactly what I want.  I don't have an easy way to test it now, since just doing plain strip and then pulling again doesn't seem to work when using hgsubversion.